# Powershell scipt to open power point and play slide show

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

Hey Can any one tell me how to open power point and play slide show

I have the following code but it isnt working

```
$ppAdvanceOnTime = 2
 $ppShowTypeKiosk = 3
 $ppSlideShowDone = 5

Add-type -AssemblyName office
$Application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
$application.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
$path = "C:\Users\asuribha\Desktop\Web.pptx"



 $presentation = $application.Presentations.open($path)

$presentation.SlideShowSettings.AdvanceMode = $ppAdvanceOnTime 
$presentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowType =  $ppShowTypeKiosk 

$presentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide = 1
$presentation.SlideShowSettings.EndingSlide = $presentation.Slides.Count

Do
 {
    $presenatation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View.
    if (Err<>0)
    {
        Exit Do
    }

}       

 until ($presenatation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View.State = $ppSlideShowDone)






$application.quit()

[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

This code opens power point but doesnt play the slide show !!! I also have a problem with this it sometimes automatically closes the power point.
Please Help me out with this

Comment: Sometimes you use $presentation, sometimes $presenatation; surely they should be consistent?

Comment: SORRY  i overlooked that. I have changed that but still it doesnt work

Comment: Can you launch PowerPoint via command line?  If so, you can use (something like) C:\PathTo\PowerPnt.EXE /s c:\PathTo\YourShow.PPTX (substitute the appropriate paths for "PathTo"

Comment: I'm not a PowerShell guy, but this looks wrong to me too:  $presenatation.SlideShowSettings.Run.View.  There shouldn't be a dot at the end, and to launch the show, at least in VBA, you'd use .SlideShowSettings.Run on the presentation object

Answer (score 3):

I have troubled with alot of the above from various sites and eventually found this to be the quickest and got no problems even if powerpoint wasn't running the machine it was still able to carry on.  I basically wanted to run a script the receptionist could input details without any complications just an input box then on finishing it would run another powershell on the presentation screen.

here's the receptionist input powershell input.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$PPTFile = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter FileName', 'Powerpoint File', "$env")
$pptx = "d:\Presentations"+($pptfile)+".pptx"
$pptx | Out-File "\\(machine name)\Scripts\Powerpoint.txt"
```

I can probably simplify it more later with remote run the powershell but at present as a powershell newbie I run the other script at the other end and all running fine.

```
Stop-Process -name "POWERPNT"
$Power = Get-Content "d:\Scripts\Powerpoint.txt"
write-output $Power
$powerptx = "/s "+($Power)
```

start-process powerpnt.exe -ArgumentList "$powerptx"

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not a very big fan of powershell, but I use this script to rotate presentations on a monitor we have:

```
$ppt = "c:\presentation.pptx"
$new_file = "c:\new.pptx"

function runloop {       
    $running = get-process POWERPNT
    $killed = $false
    if (Test-Path $new_file) {
          Write-Host "Killing"
          kill -name POWERPNT          
          Start-Sleep -s 2
          Move-Item $new_file $ppt -force
          $killed = $true
    }    
    if (!$running -or $killed) {
          Write-Host "Not running"
          $app = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
          $pres = $app.Presentations.open($ppt)
          $app.visible = "msoTrue"
          $pres.SlideShowSettings.Run()                         
          $pres.visible = "msoTrue"
    }    
    Write-Host "Done"
}

runloop;
```

Hacky, but it works for me. Hope this helps.