# Open PowerPoint and then SaveAs

Tags: powershell, powerpoint, ps1

I am not programmer and I need help. I would like to script my daily task.

- Open PowerPoint (.pptx format) - DONE
- Press 'A' button to update numbers from Excel - DONE
- Save PowerPoint (.pptx format) - Do not know how to do it
- And then save PowerPoint again in .ppsx format and Close it - Do not know how to do it

How to do it please? I tried to create .ps1 script, but do not know how to continue.

There is my code:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "\\192.168.1.2\I\IT\Public\TV\NM\PrezentaceNM.pptx"

Start-Sleep -s 15

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.SendKeys('A')

Start-Sleep -s 45
```

Answer (score 0):

to open PowerPoint files using script can be found here -

**Presentations.Open method (PowerPoint)**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Presentations.Open

**PowerShell Script to open Powerpoint and play a slide show**

[Powershell scipt to open power point and play slide show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650968/powershell-scipt-to-open-power-point-and-play-slide-show)

To Open & Close PowerPoint Using PowerShell

```
##File Path
$PowerpointFile = ""\\192.168.1.2\I\IT\Public\TV\NM\PrezentaceNM.pptx""
##Create Com Object
$Powerpoint = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
$ppt = $Powerpoint.presentations.open($PowerpointFile, $True, $False)

$ppt.  ##Do Stuff

Sleep -Seconds 3
$ppt.Save()
$Powerpoint.Quit()
```

Comment: I can start the pptx and press A I just need to know how to save the file in powershell. Can you edit my code please?

Comment: add $wshell.save() to your script.

Comment: I tried but it is not working. The only thing I need right now is to Save file and then SaveAs and close :( Can't find any hint how to save pptx with powershell.

Comment: try like this 

$savePath = "\\192.168.1.2\I\IT\Public\TV\NM\"
$wshell.TargetPath = $savePath
$wshell.Save()

Answer (score 0):

I moved little bit forward. Now I need to know how to add SaveAs and save it as ppsx. Any Idea?
Current code:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "\\192.168.1.2\I\IT\Public\TV\NM\PrezentaceNM.pptx"

Start-Sleep -s 15

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.SendKeys('A')

Start-Sleep -s 40

$wshell.SendKeys('^(s)')

Start-Sleep -s 15

Stop-Process -Name POWERPNT
```